# Java lambda operations on hierarchy objects

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to count (or list) all artists that are from US. If the Artist object is solo, then it is person that can be count directly. If it is not solo, then it is a band that consists of artists/members. We need to count the members.

My current code is as follow:

```
    long count = allArtists.stream()
              .filter(artist -> artist.isFrom("US") && artist.isSolo())
              .count();
    long count2 = allArtists.stream()
            .filter(artist -> artist.isFrom("US") && !artist.isSolo())
            .flatMap(artist -> artist.getMembersAsStream())
            .count();
    long result = count + count2;
```

While the code is working, I noticed that it performs two repetitive operations on filtering the allArtists which may hurt performance. How to improve the lambda expressions? I am thinking of using partitionBy, but have no clue at the moment.

Comment: What would `getMemberAsStream()` return if the artist `isSolo() == true`?

Comment: @cheffe: It will return Stream<Artist>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
long result = allArtists.stream()
          .filter(artist -> artist.isFrom("US"))
          .flatMap(artist -> artist.isSolo() ? Stream.of(artist)
                                             : artist.getMembersAsStream())
          .count();
```